# How to suppress legend display in Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

Is there a parameter for the Dygraphs **legend** option (*e.g.*, 'never') that will hide the legend entirely?  I'm looking for the opposite of "always", and hoping there is a cleaner way to suppress the legend than associating it with its own **labelsDiv**, creating that div, and styling that div's visibility as "hidden".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated, there doesn't seem to be an explicit option right now, but you can easily set the labelsDivWidth option to 0 to hide it.

```
options.labelsDivWidth = 0;
```

Comment: I've switched my preference to this answer, as it provides the "cleanest" solution.  I've replaced the **labelsDiv: "dygraphLabelsContainer"** option with **labelsDivWidth: 0**, and deleted the <div> tag and documentation:
`<div id="dygraphLabelsContainer"          style="position:absolute:left:0px;top:0px;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1">
This is the only way to hide the graph legend
</div>`

Answer (score 3):

I think the option to supress the legend display is now explicitly available in version 2.0.0:

```
showLabelsOnHighlight: false
```

Answer (score 2):

That option doesn't exist. [The project source code](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/dygraph.js) (on lines 289 and 290) says

```
// TODO(danvk): support 'onmouseover' and 'never', and remove synonyms.
legend: 'onmouseover',  // the only relevant value at the moment is 'always'.
```

Therefore, for now you have to create a div with visibility as "hidden".

Comment: Thanks for the source code link.  Good to know that 'never' is on the radar.  The hidden <div> works fine for now.